# SoapUI: differences in arrow meaning opposite to method names?

Tags: soapui

What is the difference in arrow types (one direction VS bi-directional) opposite to method names? What do they mean in terms of web-services?

[image]

Seems like:

- one direction - there should not be any responce
- bi-directional - responce is expected

Is it so?

**UPDATE:** according to answer of @MichalBabich I have checked `wsdl-file` and there is correlation

One direction arrow (One-way Operation):

```
    <wsdl:operation name="nmtoken">
       <wsdl:input name="nmtoken"? message="qname"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

Bi-directional arrow (Request-response Operation):

```
    <wsdl:operation name="nmtoken" parameterOrder="nmtokens">
       <wsdl:input name="nmtoken"? message="qname"/>
       <wsdl:output name="nmtoken"? message="qname"/>
       <wsdl:fault name="nmtoken" message="qname"/>*
    </wsdl:operation>
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Are both REST services?

Comment: @Rao ,  SoapUI 5.3.0, both are SOAP services

Comment: I could not see arrow type service operations on 5.3. Do you know how to reproduce?

Comment: @Rao , there is not much to say: I have a link to service (http://some.link.to.web_sevices?wsdl). When I am creating new SOAP project, I am adding this link to initial WSDL field and selecting checkbox "Create sample requests for all operations?". These arrows right opposite methods with sample requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found surprisingly little on this, maybe this links will help:
https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/xml-dist-app/2006Mar/att-0037/one-way-MEP.htm

Also there are some definitions on this page: https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_porttypes

- One-way. The endpoint receives a message.
- Request-response. The endpoint receives a message, and sends a correlated message.
- Solicit-response. The endpoint sends a message, and receives a correlated message.
- Notification. The endpoint sends a message.

Also if you double click your interface (green arrows) you may see Operations and their status
[image]